# How to Change Background color App Back Button - Windows 10 - C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, back-button, back

How to change the background color of Back button in native Windows 10 apps?

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: button]

Comment: Take a look here should give you an idea of what to do http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2015/08/20/uwp-take-the-control-of-your-title-bar.aspx

Comment: Hello fipcurren88, could you please consider marking my answer as solution? Ty

Answer (score 5):

You can achive it in the code behind like this:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();              

        var appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
        appView.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.LightGreen;
    }
```

Hope it works for you

Regards
Ilija